# Вызвать плагин как функцию Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    this.fadeIn('normal', function(){
        // что-то делаем
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Таким образом наш плагин можно вызвать так:

```
$('#element').myPlugin();
```

Вопрос: что нужно изменить, что бы плагин можно было вызвать как функцию:

```
myPlugin();
```

Нужно именно плагином реализовать, а не просто функцией, так как обращаемся к нему из другого файла.

Comment: Разве функция, вызванная из другого файла, не отрабатывает?

Comment: Не понятно в чем сложность. Как раз именно плагином как импортить - неочевидно, а в чем проблема экспортить просто функцию то?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin нет почему-то

Comment: вы точно подключаете плагин после jquery в скриптах?

Comment: @teran конечно точно. Плагин то работает, но функция так не работает.

Comment: покажите листинг прикрепления файла скриптов к вашему документу и сам вызов функции, который не срабатывает, пжлста

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Что тут не понятно, сперва подключаю ajax библиотеку, затем файл plugin.js затем script.js и если в файле с плагином просто лежит функция, то она не будет работать если вызвать ее в файле script.js. А если написана не функция а плагин, то вызов работает, но вопрос не в том вообще.